# How to create screenshot for each step using gherkin and cucumber with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, testing, cucumber, gherkin

I'm trying to take a screenshot for each step or when the steps are passed

Comment: I solve this in java by `private void stepWrapper(Runnable r) { r.run(); takeScreenshot();}` and surround every step with `stepWrapper(() -> {step code here;});` (lambda func) Hope something similar is possible in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a screenshot after each step is not recommended by Cucumber, and considered somewhat of an anti-pattern.

From the [FAQ](https://cucumber.io/docs/community/faq/#taking-a-screenshot-after-failed-steps):

"Taking a screenshot when a scenario fails, might help you to figure out what went wrong. To take a screenshot on failure, you can configure an after hook.

For an example on how to use take a screenshot with WebDriver for failed scenarios and embed them in Cucumber’s report, see the browser automation page.

Below is an example of how to take a screenshot with WebDriver Below is an example of how to take a screenshot with for failed scenarios and embed them in Cucumber’s report.

Note that taking a screenshot after every step is considered an anti-pattern. You should be able to rely on your test automation, without having to check every step of your scenario with a screenshot. Your automation should be stable and tests should fail for a clear reason."